# Change SRC in Android BitMap

Tags: android, bitmap, src

Im using BitMap in my XMP and one of the key points of bitmap is the SRC tag - that is the tag where the Drawable is located so that the BitMap knows what to show.

Okay, and now I would like to change the Bitmap SRC from the code.

TextView has for example the `Method.setText(String)` and I was looking for something simmilar with bitmaps - like `BitMap.setSrc(R.drawable.something)` but I couldnt fond anything simmilar.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save an existing Bitmap you can use the [compress method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) of the Bitmap class. You have to create a FileOutputStream and hand it over to the compress method.

If you want to open a Bitmap from the file system you can use the [decodeFile method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29) of the BitmapFactory.

Comment: You maybe did not understand my question. In one Layout I use as a background a XML that had a BITMAP inside - that makes me a background that is not going to scale. And my question is If im able to change the XML - SRC TAG for the BitMap - so the background can be changhed?

Comment: Could you clarify your question then and post the XML?

Comment: IF you use an ImageView you can use the setImageBitmap() method. imageview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.something);